# Mapping RFC names to OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

## Passing string didn't work

I want to get a cipher using `EVP_get_cipherbyname`, I have the following

- RFC name: `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`

which should map to this

- OpenSSL name: `DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`.

But when passing this string to the function, it can't find the cipher.

## Passing integer didn't work

Using `openssl -V` I can see this is a supported cipher, and that it has a value `0x9e` which is `158` in base 10, I have assumed that this would be the NID, and tried calling `EVP_get_cipherbynid` with `158`, but alas doesn't work either although I don't think this is the NID anymore.

## What works?

How do I get a mapping of the RFC names to names that OpenSSL will accept?

Comment: My web search engine provides this table for this usage: [Mapping OpenSSL cipher suite names to RFC names](https://testssl.sh/openssl-rfc.mappping.html).

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf I tried using that table, ie. the `DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256` but it can't find the cipher

Comment: As per @RoraZ, `EVP_get_cipherbyname` only gives you a symmetric cipher with mode, not an SSL/TLS ciphersuite. The names (plus some alternate "nicknames") of EVP ciphers can be listed with `openssl list-cipher-algorithms`, and includes many that are not used in SSL/TLS. You can't directly lookup a ciphersuite; you can (only) enable one or more ciphersuite(s) using the individual and/or category names on the `ciphers` manpage and after the handshake completes look at the single ciphersuite that was negotiated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you're confusing **cipher suites** and **ciphers**.

`EVP_get_cipherbyname()` does not take the name of a cipher suite it takes the name of a cipher.  The `man` page and general documentation for the OpenSSL API is pretty terrible.  But searching for "EVP_get_cipherbyname" in [this PDF](http://www.clizio.com/S3/documenti/Miscellanea/OpenSSLcrypto.pod.pdf) yields 6 results.  The very last reference is in a section talking about PEM encoded certificates.  Now I know this isn't what you're doing, but it contains the following quote:

> The line beginning DEK-Info contains two comma
>   separated pieces of information: the **encryption algorithm name as used
>   by EVP_get_cipherbyname()** and an 8 byte salt encoded as a set of
>   hexadecimal digits.

The line they're referring to is: `DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,3F17F5316E2BAC8`

Which means that EVP_get_cipherbyname() really takes `DES_3DE3-CBC` as input, not a cipher suite.   For your case I believe you're looking for `AES-128-GCM` to get the correct **cipher**.

---

NID simply stands for Numerical ID.  This is a generic term for identifying a set list.  Cipher suites do not have NIDs only the RFC assigned codes (thanks @dave_thompson_085).  Which is why when you attempted to use the NID it still couldn't find the cipher.

Comment: Exactly. The difference is between `EVP_CIPHER` which represents (only) a symmetric cipher instance (algorithm, mode, key, IV/params) versus `SSL_CIPHER` which describes an SSL/TLS ciphersuite with key-exchange and authentication method, symmetric cipher with keysize and mode, and mac hash if applicable, plus other internal attributes. But ciphersuites don't have OIDs or (therefore) NIDs, only the RFC-assigned codes.

Comment: @RoraZ: Like it. You wouldn't, by any chance, know where to get that PDF for the current OpenSSL version?

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell you how to get a cipher suite by IANA cipher suite hexcode. But maybe this answer can still help a bit.

## Use table manually.

Lazy answer: Use the handy [TestSSL.sh table](https://testssl.sh/openssl-rfc.mappping.html) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/HSUx2).)

> [0x9e],    *DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256*,    DH, AESGCM, 128,    **TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256**

Or use the [official OpenSSL name mapping table](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html) (which sadly lacks hexcodes).

## NID is different.

There are <s>two types of NIDs</s> many, many types of NID (EDIT. See Dave's comment below for details.) such as these:

- (Bulk) Cipher NID
- Digest NID

As far as I can tell, they were [introduced in April 2015](https://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=commitdiff;h=98c9ce2f55609d00a06c2106df03a5a7e9dbfa75).

In contrast, the [official hexcodes in the TLS Cipher Suite Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml)
are for COMBINATIONS of crypto-building-blocks (bulk-cipher, digest, key-exchange, authentication, etc.) And not for the individual building blocks.

Comment: I tried using  `DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`, which is the "mapping" in the table you linked, and passing it to `EVP_get_cipherbyname` but it fails, ie. can't find the cipher

Comment: @Chaosekie: Sorry. My bad. Didn't read your post very carefully it seems. But: Could you please add the exact error message?

Comment: I'm not currently at a pc where I can compile the code, I will add the error message asap

Comment: NIDs in OpenSSL are an internal equivalent of an ASN.1 OID (Object Identifier) and there are hundreds of them for all kinds of things: symmetric ciphers, modes, and variants, digests, PRFs, (PB and nonPB) KDFs, attributes and extensions in certificates, CRLs, CSRs, CMS/SMIME messages, PKCS8 and PKCS12 keys, and there have been since the early 0.9 versions in the 1990s. What is new is mapping ciphersuites to the NIDs as well as names of two of their building blocks (as you correctly call them).

Comment: By the way, Mozilla has a nice cipher suite correspondence table https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Cipher_Suites

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to convert any OpenSSL (or GnuTLS, NSS, etc.) cipher name into IANA/standard/RFC cipher names  or hexadecimal codepoints or teh other way around by using [tls-map](https://github.com/sec-it/tls-map) library in ruby:

```rb
require 'tls_map'

tm = TLSmap::App.new

# OpenSSL -> IANA
tm.search(:openssl, 'AES128-SHA', :iana) #=> {:iana=>"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"}
# Hexadecimal codepoint to all (including OpenSSL & IANA)
tm.search(:codepoint, '1303') #=> {:codepoint=>"1303", :iana=>"TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", :openssl=>"TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", :gnutls=>"CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", :nss=>"TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256"}
```

It's also available as a CLI tool:

```
$ tls-map search openssl AES128-SHA -o iana
iana: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```