# OpenSSL 1.1 get a cipher suite by the IANA ID

Tags: c, openssl

In OpenSSL **1.0.2** we have used the `ssl3_get_cipher_by_id()` function found in `s3_lib.c` to obtain a cipher suite (`SSL_CIPHER*`) using the IANA ID.

For example, the ID `0x00,0x2F` would give us the `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` cipher suite as an `SSL_CIPHER` struct.

However, this function is not listed in the OpenSSL documentation from **1.0.2** and above, and while the function is still available in **1.1.1** it does not seem to work for newer cipher suites, e.g. returning NULL for both of these:

```
0xC0,0x2F TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
0xC0,0x14 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

**MY QUESTION:** Is there a modern way to obtain the cipher suite (`SSL_CIPHER` or *newer* struct) by its IANA ID?

I have seen [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483878/mapping-rfc-names-to-openssl) but it does not answer how to obtain a cipher suite object from an IANA hex ID.

N.B. by IANA ID I mean the first hex column on pages like these:

- https://testssl.sh/openssl-iana.mapping.html
- https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Cipher_Suites
- https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xml#tls-parameters-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use SSL_CIPHER_find(), which

> ... returns a SSL_CIPHER structure which has the cipher ID stored in ptr. The ptr parameter is a two element array of char, which stores the two-byte TLS cipher ID (as allocated by IANA) in network byte order.

see https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CIPHER_find.html

**C Program**

C code for your two examples could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

static void print_name(unsigned char iana[], const SSL_CIPHER *cipher);

int main(void) {
    SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());
    SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    if (ssl == NULL) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    unsigned char iana1[] = {0xC0, 0x2F};
    const SSL_CIPHER *cipher = SSL_CIPHER_find(ssl, iana1);
    if (cipher) {
        print_name(iana1, cipher);
    }

    unsigned char iana2[] = {0xC0, 0x14};
    cipher = SSL_CIPHER_find(ssl, iana2);
    if (cipher) {
        print_name(iana2, cipher);
    }
    SSL_free(ssl);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 0;
}

static void print_name(unsigned char iana[], const SSL_CIPHER *cipher) {
    const char *name = SSL_CIPHER_standard_name(cipher);
    if (name == NULL)
        name = "?";
    printf("0x%02X,0x%02X -> %s\n", iana[0], iana[1], name);
}
```

**Test**

If you run the above program, you will get the following output on the debug console:

```
0xC0,0x2F -> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
0xC0,0x14 -> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what we needed!

Comment: @NealEastwood do you know the way to obtain IANA ID of cipher programmatically?

Comment: @Ilyakom Depends on your starting point.

If you already have an `SSL_CIPHER*` then you could check the API description of `int SSL_CIPHER_get_cipher_nid(const SSL_CIPHER *c);` to see if it does what you want. Avoid `uint32_t SSL_CIPHER_get_id(const SSL_CIPHER *c);` because "That ID is not the same as the IANA-specific ID."

If you don't already have an `SSL_CIPHER*` it'd depend on your data source. In my case it is direct parsing of a libpcap network packet containing TLS records, so I can simply extract the cipher suite ID bytes directly from the packet.

Comment: @NealEastwood Thank you for your reply. The idea is to get supported ciphers using WinApi and then map them to OpenSSL ciphers. There are two way of doing it, first is to use mapping table from testssl, second is to do it on fly. And second way is quite complicated, because I know how to get Win cipher names, but have no idea how to get ID. If I would have ID I would be able to use SSL_CIPHER_find.
May be it's a separate question.