# Is there a way to access the IANA id of a Cipher using OpenSSL 1.0.2?

Tags: openssl

In OpenSSL `1.1.1` I can call `SSL_CIPHER_get_protocol_id`([docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CIPHER_get_protocol_id.html)) to get the IANA value of a cipher, but this function doesn't exist in `1.0.2`. Is there an alternative I can use in this older version?

Comment: Checking out [the function's source code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/fd78df59b0f656aefe96e39533130454aa957c00/ssl/ssl_ciph.c#L1896-L1899) might help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer on [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63491644/openssl-1-1-get-a-cipher-suite-by-the-iana-id/63495368#63495368), using `SSL_CIPHER_find()` in OpenSSL 1.1.

If this answer doesn't satisfy your need or if you are open to use another language, here is a solution in ruby using [tls-map](https://github.com/sec-it/tls-map).

```rb
require 'tls_map'

tm = TLSmap::App.new

tm.search(:openssl, 'AES128-SHA', :iana) #=> {:iana=>"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"}
```